# How do I avoid the empty textbox after postback?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have Created some Controls(1 Text Box,2 Drop down) with java script dynamic. I mean, in my page there is one button, when I Clicked on the button, controls will be created. but when all controls(dynamic controls and other controls) post to server(with submit button) and come back error(for example, because one text in one Text Box is wrong), all text in controls that created dynamic, was empty... I Dont want this...I want after post back all data keep...what should i do?
thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about a sort of [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

> is the technique used by an ASP.NET Web page to persist changes to the
>   state of a Web Form across postbacks.

In a nutshell, to mantain the state of your controls over the *postbacks*, you could use an `hidden-field` related every dynamic control you have, or a unique hidden field for all controls. Every update on dynamic control will update related hidden info, and at the reload every dynamic control will be updated by related hidden info.

**EDIT**

OK, probably I was still sleeping, anyway, for your task, the simplest way is:

add the '*name*' attribute to all client controls, then at the page load check if `IsPostBack`, then, if it is, scrap the `Request.Form` by key('name' attribute), finally re-inject the values to your client controls